problem when making file .ipynb Jupyter Notebook
Can I make Jupyter notebook file (.ipynb) without open the notebook? like when you make any extention just write the extention in the file explorer's floder after that it convert to that kind of file. i have tried it but it didn't work. i just want to make .ipynb at another root folder in file explorer, because of that i don't want to make it on Jupyter notebook directly because jupyter notebook itself always open the default (C:/... ) folder and i don't know how to open the other path (i have tried "open from path", but it didn't work as well), i want to make .ipynb in documents folder

Is this what you're looking for? How to create and open a jupyter notebook ipynb file directly from terminal. I don't use Jupyter very much myself, but I found that by googling "create blank ipynb".

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips like starting with your own research.

You can make a Jupyter notebook file with an .ipynb extension on the command line or Python interpreter console using nbformat. See here, as there is a step where a new notebook is made via Python code. You can just leave out putting in the content. nbformat is part of the underlying tech that Jupyter uses and so if it is installed, you can use it. Then you don't need to actually open Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab to make a .ipynb file. In the guide wjandrea references, you should look into what it says about making a good title, too.
